# Определение 2-х одинаковых классов не даёт ошибки

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
//Файл A.cpp
class A
{
public:
    int func( int i )
    {
        return i*i;
    }
};

//Файл Test.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int func( int i )
    {
        return i*i*i;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    cout<<a.func(2)<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Вопрос в том, почему нет ошибки времени компиляции? Ведь имеется два определения класса с именем А. Программа работает - выводит 8.

Дополню вопрос.
Если переписать файл "A.cpp" так:

```
class A
{
public:
    int func( int i );
};

int A::func( int i )
{
    return i*i;
}
```

То ошибка будет!!!

С функциями аналогичная ситуация. Приведённый ниже код работать не будет.

```
//A.cpp
int func( int i )
{
    return i*i;
}

//Test.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int func( int i )
{
    return i*i*i;
}


int main()
{
    cout<<func(2)<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Всё это меня как-то запутывает.

Comment: я не знаток крестов, но это происходит скорее всего потому что у обоих классов область видимости ограничена файлами, в которых они находятся

Comment: Вообще дурной тон писать определение классов в *.cpp файлах

Comment: Тут можно говорить только об ошибке линковщика а не компилятора.

Comment: @zenden2k
Ой, да, не так выразился. Ну, т.е. не ошибка компиляции, а ошибка времени компиляции.

Comment: А как вы компилируете? Может, a.cpp случайно не попадает в линковку? Например, может быть, вы его забыли скомпилировать?

Comment: @VladD В Visual Studio 2012 жмякаю на зелёненькую стрелочку :)

Comment: @VladD gcc-4.9.2 то же самое

Comment: А почему никто не плюсует вопрос?

Comment: Пожалуй самое тут интересное (для меня) это то, что  A.cpp только с классом компилируется в пустой .o (проще всего посмотреть, например вывод gcc -S -- ни инструкций, ни констант, ничего материального)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Согласно стандарту языка (правилу ODR) классы с external linkage (внешним связыванием), определенные в нескольких единицах трансляции, должны быть определены одинаково во всех этих единицах трансляции. Но диагностики этого не требуется.

Точно так же, по ODR, inline-функции с external linkage, определенные в нескольких единицах трансляции, должны быть определены одинаково во всех этих единицах трансляции. Но диагностики этого не требуется.

В вашем исходном примере наличествуют как раз две таких сущности - класс с external linkage и inline-функция с external linkage.

Т.е. спецификация языка *требует*, чтобы эти сущности были определены одинаково во всех единицах трансляции, но следить за этой одинаковостью - в общем случае ваша задача. Продвинутый компилятор может помочь вам ловить такие ошибки, но это просто вопрос качества реализации.

Как только ваша функция перестала быть inline, диагностика для нарушений ODR для такой функции сразу же формально потребовалась и компилятор ее успешно вам предоставил.

Answer (score 4):

В стандарте не уточняется, должен ли компилятор выдавать диагностическое сообщение, если нарушено правило одного определения. Он только говорит, что в этом случае поведение программы неопределенное (Раздел Стандарта "3.2 One definition rule", параграф 6).

> ...If the definitions of D do not satisfy these requirements, then **the
>   behavior is undefined.**

Иногда в нем явно указывается, что компилятор не обязан выдавать диагностическое сообщение, как в этой фразе (там же, параграф 4)

> 4...Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline
>   function or variable that is odr-used in that program; **no diagnostic
>   required**.

Даже для того случая, когда вы определили в модуле A функцию вне класса без спецификатора функции `inline`, а в другом модуле она была определена внутри класса, а потому по умолчанию считается `inline-функцией`, и ваш компилятор (или линкер) выдал сообщение об ошибке, то даже в этом случае на самом деле компиляторы не обязаны выдавать диагностическое сообщение (Раздел "7.1.2 Function specifiers"):

> 4...If a function with external linkage is declared inline in one
>   translation unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units
>   in which it appears; **no diagnostic is required.**

Это практически невозможно диагностировать компилятору.

Вы должны довольствоваться неопределенным поведением программы.:)

Answer (score 1):

Test.cpp не знает о существовании A.cpp. Поэтому, используется класс из Test.cpp, в котором число возводится в куб.

Если код из этих двух файлов переписать в один, то ошибка появится.

Comment: "Test.cpp не знает о существовании A.cpp."
Я про это много раз слышал. Вот только вы попробуйте сделать тоже самое с функциями, а не с классами. Ничего не получится!!!